When there are multiple of the same character in play, which one(s) do character-based actions apply to?
There are some characters like Legion and Village Idiot that more than one player can be at the same time. So what happens when another character's ability requires selecting a character? For example:

A Courtier chooses Legion. Which Legion player is drunk? Does exactly one become drunk, or do both of them?
The Ojo chooses to kill the Village Idiot. Do they all die, or does only one die?


When an ability says "(choose) a character" and multiple copies of that character are in play, the Storyteller chooses one such player.
The ability applies to just that player, even if they later become a different character (because generally, references to "a character" apply to the player with that character, who is then explicitly marked).
We see this clarity given specifically at least for Ojo

If there are multiple copies of a particular character in play, and the Ojo chooses that character to die, only one of those characters dies.

and the same principle is applied in comparable situations.
Courtier choosing Legion only makes one Legion player drunk; Ojo choosing Village Idiot only makes one V.I. die; Philosopher choosing a multiple-in-play character only makes one of that character drunk.
